# Vim: How can I synchronise NERDtree with terminal pane

Tags: vim, nerdtree

My Vim session currently resembles this:

```
+-----------------------+
| NT  | Open file       |
|     |                 |
|     |-----------------+
|     | Terminal        |
|     |                 |
+-----------------------+
```

A bit like VSCode or any other standard IDE. Is there a way I can get the location of the terminal to change along with the folder I have navigated to in the NERDtree file explorer?

Comment: Does NERDTree emit something that can be observed when you change directory?

Comment: For now I'm using Terminator to open a pane below with a script that changes into the same directory.